# PostgreSQL add each item to list - DB functions

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, stored-functions

I'd like to create a DB function that will accept a list of numbers and return a list of numbers. For each item in the list that was passed to the function, it should check some condition and add it to the response list. However, I don't think the way I am trying to do it is really a correct one. What I tried writing is basically some pseudo code here.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION map_numbers(numbers integer[])
returns integer[]
AS 
$BODY$
   DECLARE return_list integer[];

   FOREACH field IN ARRAY numbers LOOP
      CASE
         WHEN field = 3 THEN -- add 43 (this was a random thought, but I am basically trying to map a few of the numbers to different values)
      END
   END LOOP;

RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM return_list;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put this into an `IF` statement. To [append](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) a value to an array use `||`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION map_numbers(numbers integer[])
returns integer[]
AS 
$BODY$
DECLARE 
  return_list integer[] := integer[];
BEGIN
  FOREACH field IN ARRAY numbers LOOP
    if field = 3 then 
      return_list := return_list || 43;
    elsif field = 15 then 
      return_list := return_list || 42;
    else
      return_list := return_list || field;
    end if;
  END LOOP;
  return return_list; --<< no SELECT required, just return the variable
END;  
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql --<< you need PL/pgSQL, not SQL for the above
STABLE;
```

---

This can also be done using SQL rather than PL/pgSQL which usually is more efficient:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION map_numbers(numbers integer[])
  returns integer[]
AS 
$BODY$
  select array_agg(field order by idx)
  from (
    select case 
              when field = 3 then 43
              when field = 15 then 42
              else field
           end as field,
           idx
    from unnest(numbers) with ordinality as t(field, idx)
  ) x;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql 
STABLE;
```